# Stata split string into parts

Tags: regex, stata

I have a string variable (`col1`) that I want to **split at the first occurrence of an integer**, i.e. generate variables `part1` and `part2`.

```
               col1                part1    part2
--------------------------------------------------
    AufderScholle12        AufderScholle       12
Kˆnigsbr¸ckerPlatz3   Kˆnigsbr¸ckerPlatz        3
         Hansastr0A             Hansastr       0A
             Flur:3                Flur:        3
```

I could not figure out yet how to implement that using regex expressions from various articles on this matter.

Comment: `^(\D*)(\d?.*)$` - part 1 would be in the first capture group (backreference `\1` or `$1`), part 2 would be in the second. Regex demo here: https://regex101.com/r/tU0nI2/2

Comment: just spit your input according to `(?<=\D)(?=\d+)` regex.

Comment: @AvinashRaj, that works if one has lookaround at one's disposal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works for your example data, but notice I had to insert the "non-conventional" characters inside the regex definition because I don't see a way of expressing "all but numbers" using Stata's implementation of regex:

```
clear
set more off

*----- example data -----

input ///
str30 orig              
"AufderScholle12"       
"K^nigsbr¸ckerPlatz3"   
"Hansastr0A"          
"Flur:3"
end

list

*----- what you want -----

gen p1 = regexs(1) if(regexm(orig, "([\-\^\¸\:a-zA-Z]*)([0-9]?.*)"))
gen p2 = regexs(2) if(regexm(orig, "([\-\^\¸\:a-zA-Z]*)([0-9]?.*)"))

list
```

The regex experts can take a look at Stata's implementation (a very simple one) here:

http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/regular-expressions/

to check for a better way.

According to Stata's [help regex](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?regex)

> Regular expression syntax is based on Henry Spencer's NFA algorithm,
>   and this is nearly identical to the POSIX.2 standard.

A solution I'm more confident in uses *string functions*:

```
clear
set more off

*----- example data -----

input ///
str30 orig              
"AufderScholle12"       
"K^nigsbr¸ckerPlatz3"   
"Hansastr0A"          
"Flur:3"
end

list

*----- what you want -----

forvalues i = 0/9 {
    gen p_`i' = strpos(orig, "`i'")
    replace p_`i' = . if p_`i' == 0
}

egen fpos = rowmin(p*)

gen p1 = substr(orig, 1, fpos-1)
gen p2 = substr(orig, fpos, .)

drop fpos p_*
list
```

This just finds the position where the first numeric character occurs and uses that to single out substrings from the original text.

See `help string functions`.

### Edit

One way of expressing "all but numbers" is `[^0-9]*`, so the following would give the same results as the original:

```
gen p3 = regexs(1) if(regexm(orig, "([^0-9]*)([0-9]?.*)"))
gen p4 = regexs(2) if(regexm(orig, "([^0-9]*)([0-9]?.*)"))
```

Comment: This did the job, thank you for your help! It required some adjustments but that was easy once I had the code snippet from your post...

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a complete answer, just a footnote to @Roberto Ferrer's useful answer that would not go well as a comment.

Another way to find the position of the first integer, without creating 10 new variables and then firing up `egen`:

```
gen posint = . 
quietly forval i = 0/9 { 
    replace posint = min(posint, strpos(orig, "`i'")) 
}
```